# Opening NSDocument based app loads two windows

Tags: swift, macos, nsdocument

I have a simple NSDocument based app that has two text fields (Imagine a git differ). When I open my file, it opens two windows with my file name. Everything works great on the first window. The second's UI is empty with the same file name.

```swift
override func makeWindowControllers() {
    // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
    let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("Document Window Controller")) as! NSWindowController
    self.addWindowController(windowController)
}

override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {

    if let fileString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {

        makeWindowControllers()

        guard let vc = windowControllers.first?.contentViewController as? ViewController else {
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
        }

        guard let inputString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
        }

        let doc = JsonConverter().convertToJSONFrom(string: inputString)

        if let a = doc["a"] as? String {
            vc.leftTextView.string = a
        }

        if let b = doc["b"] as? String {
            vc.rightTextView.string = b
        }

    } else {
        throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: Main UI]

I don't get where the second one (on the right) is coming from.

**edit:** I just noticed that if I double click a saved file, I get this error which oddly enough, does NOT fire from any of those NSErrors in the read() function.

Fwiw, Open from the menu is what I was referring to above.

**edit 2:** Correction. 'Sometimes' it opens two windows. But even when it does that, both are empty. What I don't get is that this read function is so simple, there isn't much to go wrong. It feels like it's all going sideways under the hood.

[image: Error when double clicking file.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't get where the second one (on the right) is coming from.

It looks like it's probably coming from your `read()` function, which calls `makeWindowControllers()`. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515220-makewindowcontrollers):

> *This method is called by the NSDocumentController open... methods, but you might want to call it directly in some circumstances.*

When a document is opened, it is of course also read, so `makeWindowControllers()` is being called twice: once by the document's built-in open behavior, and once by your `read()` override.

> Correction. 'Sometimes' it opens two windows. But even when it does that, both are empty.

Perhaps you've got an occasional error that prevents the document to even getting to the `read()` call.

> if I double click a saved file, I get this error

That supports the idea that something is going wrong before you even get to `read()`. You can find out easily enough by putting a log message in `read()` and checking the console for that message after a case where only one window opens. Also, do you have any `application(open...)` methods overridden in your app delegate? Perhaps one of those is responsible for the error.

**Update:**

After messing around a bit with a simple document-based project, I found that `NSDocument` does indeed call `makeWindowControllers()` for you, but it does so **after** it calls `read()`. A breakpoint in your `read()` method will show that there are no view controllers because `makeWindowControllers()` hasn't been called yet. Here's my `read()` method:

```
override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    // makeWindowControllers();
    guard let text = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
    self.content = text
}
```

If I uncomment the call to `makeWindowControllers()`, I get the same symptom that you're asking about: two windows open, and only one of them shows the content. If I create a new document, though, I only get one window because the `read()` method never gets called.

> So this app is very basic at this point. View controller has a couple outlets and sets the text in NSTextViewDelegate's textDidChange function. But that's it. App delegate default, then the Document class. If I don't call makeWindowControllers then windowControllers is empty. If I call it, then I have 1 controller, which is what I use to update the UI. Not really sure how to get around that.

You're trying to do too much in your `read()` method. `NSDocument` is very MVC-oriented, and you can think of the document as a kind of controller — it ties the views and the data together. The `read()` method is meant to let you read the data, and the views aren't created until after that. I think that's probably because the data might determine what kind of view to create. My document class has a `content` property that's just a string, and `read()` just grabs the data from the file and sticks it in the string. In my case, `makeWindowControllers()` gets called for me automatically, and my override uses `content` to set up the window:

```
override func makeWindowControllers() {
    // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
    let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("Document Window Controller")) as! WindowController
    windowController.text = self.content
    self.addWindowController(windowController)
}
```

> Also, if I comment out the call to makeWindowControllers, it never gets called when I open a file. Logging proves that its only called once with the manual call and zero times without it.

I don't have a good explanation for this if your log statement is in `makeWindowControllers()`. It's inconsistent with what I'm seeing, so I'd ask you to a) check your work and b) add more information here, either in a comment or in your question. Again, I'm seeing `makeWindowControllers()` being called without the need to call it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. So this app is very basic at this point. View controller has a couple outlets and sets the text in NSTextViewDelegate's textDidChange function. But that's it. App delegate default, then the Document class. If I don't call `makeWindowControllers` then `windowControllers` is empty. If I call it, then I have 1 controller, which is what I use to update the UI. Not really sure how to get around that. Also, if I comment out the call to makeWindowControllers, it never gets called when I open a file. Logging proves that its only called once with the manual call and zero times without it.

Comment: Beautiful, this completely makes sense. Thanks so much.